# Overload operator[] for Char assignment - C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, char-pointer

I am fairly new to C++, although I do have some experience programming. I have built a **Text** class that uses a dynamic char* as it's main member. The **class definition** is below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;


class Text
{
  public:

    Text();
    Text(const char*); // Type cast char* to Text obj
    Text(const Text&); // Copy constructor
    ~Text();

    // Overloaded operators
    Text& operator=(const Text&);
    Text operator+(const Text&) const; // Concat
    bool operator==(const Text&) const;
    char operator[](const size_t&) const; // Retrieve char at
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const Text&);

    void get_input(istream&); // User input

  private:
    int length;
    char* str;
};
```

The issue I am having is I don't know how to use `operator[]` to **assign** a char value at the given index that's passed in. **The current overloaded operator** `operator[]` is being used to return the **char** at the index supplied. Anyone have experience with this?

I would like to be able to do something similar to:

```
int main()
{
  Text example = "Batman";
  example[2] = 'd';

  cout << example << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Any help and/or advice is appreciated!

**Solution provided** - Thanks a bunch for all the replies

`char& operator[](size_t&);` works

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading

Comment: If the solution works, then mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to provide a reference to the character.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo {
   char m_array[64];
   char& operator[](size_t index) { return m_array[index]; }
   char operator[](size_t index) const { return m_array[index]; }
};

int main() {
    Foo foo;
    foo[0] = 'H';
    foo[1] = 'i';
    foo[2] = 0;
    std::cout << foo[0] << ", " << foo.m_array << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/srBurV

Note that `size_t` is unsigned, because negative indexes are never good.

Answer (score 3):

You should overload `operator[]` as non `const` method and return a reference from it

```
char& operator[](const int&);
```

Answer (score 3):

This article is the definitive guide to operator overloading in C++ (which, to be honest, is mainly boilerplate code for syntactic sugar). It explains everything that is possible:
[Operator overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading)

Here's the portion that is of interest to you:

```
class X {
        value_type& operator[](index_type idx);
  const value_type& operator[](index_type idx) const;
  // ...
};
```

And yes, this is possible, for the many of the STL containers (the `vector` for example), allow for array subscript notation to access data.

So you can do something along the lines of this:

```
char & operator[]( size_t i )
{
    return *(str + i);
}
```